# NAGIOS - Alert when low bandwidth usage on linux interface

Tags: linux, nagios, snmp, interface

I have Nagios running and monitoring devices by snmp.
I need to monitor bandwidth usage of a Linux server interface and send an alert when its below from 100kbps of usage. Are there any plugin 
to do this? All the plugins i found are the opossite situation: alert when high bandwidth usage.  Its important to do it by snmp.

Thanks !

Comment: That's a weird request. Can you give more detail on why this is needed?

Comment: its an interface that sniff traffic. We need to know if the bandwidth usage its below than certain value because means there is some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check improved plugin `check_snmp_netint.pl` (version 2.36) of standard nagios plugin (check_snmp_int.pl) at http://william.leibzon.org/nagios/

You can specity traffic range similar to nagios format (`"-"` instead of `":"`): `-w 10-500,20-800 -c 5-700,1-900`

it fire up alarms if traffic input bill be below 5 and over 700 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Any plugin that supports the [standard Nagios threshold format](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#THRESHOLDFORMAT) can do low- or high-threshold alerts.

Edit: For example, the thresholds for "warn < 900, crit < 20" would be `-w 900: -c 20:` (if the plugin follows the spec).

Comment: I'm testing check_snmp_int.pl plugin. I found an example but for high traffic, I dont know how to modify the command for warning when its below 900kbps and critical when its below 20kbps ./check_snmp_int.pl -H xx.xx.xx.xx -C community eth1 -k -w100,50 -c0,0

Comment: i think check_snmp.int.pl plugin doesnt use standard Nagios thresholds format. I did it but always check for high traffic, even if i put 900: I need another plugin...

Answer (score 0):

check_snmp_int.pl (http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_int.html) is my go to when it comes to interface utilisation monitoring for many years.   But I had no luck trying the "colon" [:] or the "dash" [-] syntax.

check_snmp_netint.pl (http://william.leibzon.org/nagios/) also didn't seem to work with the "colon" [:] syntax.
BUT...I did find the "dash" [-] syntax seemed to do what I needed.   I was wanting to get an alert if there was low (eg. no) traffic inbound on a link.   After getting errors that -c couldn't be less than -w I thought to disable the -w alert and just get a -c alert.

I ended up with this...

/check_snmp_int.pl -H [snipped] -C [snipped] -2 -n ethernet0/1.18 -d 60 -k -B -w 0,0 -c 5-100000,0

This seems to cut alert when utilisation is below 5 Kbps or above 100,000 Kbps.
I just made the upper value excessively high as I know there will never be that much traffic on this particular link.